# mov ecx, arg - How to replicate in C++?

Tags: assembly, c++, call

I frequently see code formatted like this:

```
push arg
push arg
(...)
mov ecx, arg
call function
```

If I need to call that function in Assembly, it's fine. But since I know how to consistently get the base of the functions, for the sake of organization and simplicity, I'd like to use typedefs in a DLL to call the functions.

The problem's that I have no idea how to make a call use ecx to pass data. Unless I'm mistaken, `func(arg,arg)` will always assemble to two pushes and a call. If I don't use ecx the function crashes because it's a pointer to an object and it needs to be that. Is there any way to do this without inline assembly which I'd like to avoid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either typedef it like this:

```
// typedef <return-type>(__thiscall* <type-name>)(<ecx>, <stack-1>, <stack-2>);
typedef int(__thiscall* tSomeFunc)(int thisPtr, int arg1, int arg2);
tSomeFunc func = (tSomeFunc) 0xBAADC0DE;

// this is how you call it
func(/* this */ 0x123, /* arg1 */ 1, /* arg2 */ arg2);
```

Or directly call it:

```
((int(__thiscall*)(int, int, int)) 0xDEADBABE)(/* this */ 0x123, 1, 2);
```

It relies on the fact that your calling convention *seems* to be [`__thiscall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx), which stores the `this` pointer into `ecx` and then pushes the rest of the args to the stack.

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. I always wondered how C++ could magically tell whether functions used ret or retn %d and this explained that, too

Comment: @AcidShout, nice job including both the typedef-style _and_ the direct-call style in your answer!